# How do I style my form so that multiple inputs are on one line?

Tags: css, html, cakephp

I have the following code:

```
<?php
    echo $form->create('User', array('url' => array('controller' => 'users', 'action' =>'login')));
echo $form->input('User.username');
echo $form->input('User.password');
echo $form->end('Login');
 ?>
```

and that creates a form that looks similar to this:

```
username
[TextBox]
password
[TextBox]
```

and I want it to look like this:

```
username [TextBox]  password [TextBox]
```

Is there an option or something I can use to do this?

Comment: You might get more help tagging this question with CSS, and also by searching google for how to do inline form fields and labels with css, as this is a style question, not something that cakephp controls. The only reason it is appearing the way it is currently is because you're probably using the default styles for forms.

Comment: You can use CSS float:left for inline form

Comment: Is there anything else you need to complete this question?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

After I had struggled with css-styles I end up using tables like this:

```
<?php
echo $this->Form->create('User', array('url' => array('controller' => 'users', 'action' =>'login'))); ?>
<table>
    <tr>
        <td><?php echo $this->Form->input('User.username'); ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $this->Form->input('User.password'); ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $this->Form->button('Submit Form', array('type'=>'submit')); ?></td>
    </tr>
</table>
<?php echo $this->Form->end(); //This and "create" has to be outside <table> to pass xhtml validation ?>
```

Answer (score 2):

Either float the elements next to each other, or display them inline. I normally only use floats when they're absolutely necessary - inline elements are much simpler to work with anyway.

```
<form method="post" action="">
<fieldset>
    <dl>
        <dt><label for="username">Username:</label></dt><dd><input type="text" name="username" value="Username" id="username" /></dd>
        <dt><label for="password">Password:</label></dt><dd><input type="password" name="password" id="password" /></dd>
    </dl>
</fieldset>
</form>
```

Essentially all you need to add is either `inline-block` or `inline` to your list elements:

```
dt { display: inline; }
dd { display: inline; }
```

Preview: http://jsfiddle.net/Wexcode/Wav9B/

Answer (score -1):

Wrap all fields in one div. Float everything to the left, setting appropriate right margins. Clear the div.